# Парсинг сложной Xml в С#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net

Столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть сложная `xml`.

```
<XML id="meter">
    <DATA>
        <SRL_NUM>Watershed0001150</SRL_NUM>
        <METER_ID>Watershed-0000001150</METER_ID>
        <MAC></MAC>
        <METER_ADDR>14 ff</METER_ADDR>
        <METER_TIME>06/03/2015 00:00:00</METER_TIME>
        <REC id="0">
            <TS>06/03/2015 00:00:00</TS>
            <C1>117</C1>
            <C2>10.5</C2>
        </REC>
        <REC id="60">
            <TS>06/03/2015 01:00:00</TS>
            <C1>100</C1>
            <C2>7</C2>
        </REC>
    </DATA>
</XML>
```

Надо это десериализовать в `class`. Я не могу понять, как это сделать, если у меня может быть от `с1` до `с10000000`.

Comment: Реализовать `IXmlSerializable`

Comment: мой для вас класс с 10000000 полей съел пол-памяти моего компа, и уронил половину приложений.
Скиньте пожалуйста еще несколько примеров XML.

Comment: @CuprumBur, а почему должны быть проблемы? 10 000 000 по 8 байт это всего ~80 МБ... Ах, вы 10 000 000 полей решили завести... )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов - реализовать интерфейс `IXmlSerializable`, например:

```
[XmlRoot("XML")]
public class Xml
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")] public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("DATA")] public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("SRL_NUM")]    public string SrlNum { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("METER_ID")]   public string MeterId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("MAC")]        public string Mac { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("METER_ADDR")] public string MeterAddr { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("METER_TIME")] public string MeterTime { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("REC")]        public List<Rec> Recs { get; } = new List<Rec>();
}

public class Rec : IXmlSerializable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ts { get; set; }
    public List<double> Cs { get; } = new List<double>();

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Id = int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("id"));
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        Ts = reader.ReadElementContentAsString("TS", "");
        while (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            Cs.Add(reader.ReadElementContentAsDouble());
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartAttribute("id");
        writer.WriteValue(Id);
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();
        writer.WriteStartElement("TS");
        writer.WriteValue(Ts);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        for (int i = 0; i < Cs.Count; ++i)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("C" + (i + 1));
            writer.WriteValue(Cs[i]);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Десериализация вполне стандартна:

```
string s = @"...";
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Xml));
var xml = (Xml)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(s));
```

Comment: а если реально надо 1000000? как делать? по частям?как?

Comment: @Andryxa, ну а вы пробовали этот вариант или нет? 10 000 000 это всего 80 МБ, должно нормально работать